# Why use transistors at all for building gates? Alternatively: what about sub-transistor level optimization?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, vlsi

I was thinking about transistor design, and how the classic AND gate is composed of two transistors in series. See this image:

[image]

Now if we look at how a transistor itself is designed we can expand the transistor (NPN MOSFET for example) with the following schematic:

[image: MOSFET layout source]

So effectively our "AND gate" at the chemical level looks something like this:

[image]

Now this seems wasteful to me, since we could have easily done away the 2nd and 3rd N-type regions and instead just done:

[image: Image of AND gate with 3 N type regions and 2 gates]

Which would reduce the number of N type regions required by nearly 33%.

So I guess in a short version, why do we not do this type sub-transistor-level optimization when building circuits?

Moreover, this can be generalized beyond gates, for example, you can natively re-implement any circuit at this level of abstraction allowing you to (at the doped chemical level) get an adder or a multiplier etc. and then only have wires between these large atomic units.

Comment: In the first picture you show us BJTs while the rest of the pictures are MOSFETs.Also in the first picture that circuit isnt a AND gate.

Comment: Have you ever seen a VLSI layout? The actual gates are not usually built using discrete transistors.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have not seen one, I admit im a layman but is there a place you'd recommend to look first? Perhaps everything i'm saying here is trivial/already considered.

Comment: @MissMulan im sorry, i thought that was an AND gate diagram, i guess it was the first thing that came up on google and matched what i thought was a source wire at the top, two inputs on the left and an output at the bottom. Let me find a correct image, although a lot of them seem to have even more transistors

Comment: Then you might want to look at some info such as http://www.vlsi-expert.com/2014/11/cmos-layout-design.html?m=1 There is much more around you can find

Comment: Too short to be an answer, so I'll put it here:  Vintage 1993 IBM chip with lots of optimization like the OP is probably imagining:  http://www.righto.com/2021/03/reverse-engineering-standard-cell-logic.html  Look at how the 3-NAND is barely bigger than the 2-NAND.

Comment: Also consider what technology you will want to use, each is different and not always available.

Comment: The basic TTL NAND uses multi-emitter transistors, one emitter for each input. You can buy dual-gate FETs, which could implement the AND gates you show, although they are typically used for gain-controlled and high freqency amplifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I guess in a short version, why do we not do this type sub transistor level optimization when building circuits?

Your mistake is looking into introductory sources, where *everything* is simplified. Nobody designs AND gates out of two transistors, and nobody lays out *ICs* as if they were discrete MOSFETs. The picture of a mosfet you show is only accurate when the mosfet is alone. In an IC, lots of tricks are possible.

What you show as *effectively our "AND gate" at the chemical level looks something like* is not how it's done, and the "optimization" you show is a common layout technique, and is taken even further. Remember that ICs are 3D, not 2D, and typically the transistors on the layout aren't circular. So the cross-section you show is quite limiting and leaves a lot of the detail out.

For a good hands-on introduction to making ICs, see [Sam Zeloof's experimental results](http://sam.zeloof.xyz/first-ic/).

Answer (score 1):

It *is* done the way you draw. Most logic circuits are CMOS (contain NMOS and PMOS devices; no DC current). In general this means there are usually strings of 2 or more series connected devices, and they are connected exactly as you show -- there is no exposed drain1-to-source2 connection. This not only saves space, but also reduces parasitic capacitance which improves speed and saves power.

However there are usually equal numbers of parallel-connected devices and they cannot share connections exactly this way.